# Android Twitter Fabric's success method is not called

Tags: android, twitter

I am working on Twitter Fabric and implemented in a Fragment.
I onActivityCreated callback method of Fragment I have written this code...

```
authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(getActivity(), new Twitter(authConfig));
        mTwitterLoginButton = (TwitterLoginButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
        mTwitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Successfully Loggedin", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                TwitterSession session = result.data;
                //TwitterSession session = Twitter.getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                long uid = session.getUserId();
                String usrname = session.getUserName();
                TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                String token = authToken.token;
                String secret = authToken.secret;
                Log.d("TAG", "token :" + token + ", secret :" + secret);
                Log.d("TAG", "uid :" + uid + ", usrname :" + usrname);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                // Do something on failure
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), ""+exception, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

And in onActivityResult of Activity I have written this code...

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Pass the activity result to the fragment, which will then pass the result to the login
        // button.
        Fragment myStocks = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentIdentifier.getString(FragmentIdentifier.MY_STOCKS.getId()));
        if (myStocks != null) {
            myStocks.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

When I am clicking on Twitter login button for first time then twitter login page is launching and when I am clicking on Authorize app then going back to fragment without calling success callback.

When I am clicking on Twitter login button for second or next time then failure callback is called.

Here is failure log...

```
10-23 06:31:44.588    5173-5173/com.stockal.app E/Twitter﹕ Authorization completed with an error
    com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.handleAuthorize(TwitterAuthClient.java:110)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.authorize(TwitterAuthClient.java:101)
            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton$LoginClickListener.onClick(TwitterLoginButton.java:161)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

build.gradle -

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml -

```
<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="<KEY>" />
```

Please help me on this. Am I missing anything in code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you added this =>  <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="<KEY>" /> in manifest file?

Comment: Thanks Chirag for quick response. Ya I have added this in my app manifest. But I have one doubt, the KEY will be same for all app? If not then which key we should mentioned?

Comment: Actually when I am implementing this using Activity then its working but I am getting problem in Fragment only.

Comment: Provide full java code here. I also this code in my application and its working fine.

Comment: I have editet my question and added build.gradle and manifest content. Just now I debug the code and I am getting resultCode = -1

Comment: Can you share your working code?

Comment: Hi Chirag, I resolved this issue. Actually from activity I was passing the result to fragment but from fragment I was not passing the result to the Login button. I have this code in Fragment's onActivityCreated().  mTwitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);. Now its working :) Thank you so much

Comment: @SanniRaj :- hello sunniRa, which id use in onactivity result of Activity?findFragmentByTag(FragmentIdentifier.getString(FragmentIdentifier.MY_STOCKS.getId())); My+STOCKS.getId is What?

Comment: MY_STOCK is member of FragmentIdentifier anum

Comment: I am also facing same problem in fragment. It doesn't come in onactivityresult of fragment as well as activity containing fragment.

Comment: @Sagar Pujari Please see my code carefully. You have to pass the result from activity to fragment then from fragment to Twitter Login button. If you are not getting it then pls share you code of activity and fragment.

Comment: @SanniRaj i have asked the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340386/twitter-login-from-fabric-doesnt-work-in-fragments plz check it.

Comment: @Sagar Pujari :- I saw your post, the fragment code looks like correct. You just put this code in onActivityResult() method of Activity in which you are adding fragment.                                                              Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FRAGMENT_TAG"));
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

Comment: @Sagar Pujari :- I could not post this there, because I don't have 50 reputation.. :(

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i had implemented it same way before u answered with some help from colleagues

Comment: @Sagar Pujari :-Please edit your question and post all your code of AndroidManifest.xml, Activity, Fragment. I want want to see how you have attempted to get this...