# Twitter Login from fabric doesn't work in fragments

Tags: twitter-oauth, twitter-fabric

Authorization completed with an error

> 10-26 11:58:33.404 7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter:
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Authorize failed.
>   10-26 11:58:33.404 7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter: 
>   at
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.handleAuthorize(TwitterAuthClient.java:110)
>   10-26 11:58:33.404 7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter: 
>   at
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterAuthClient.authorize(TwitterAuthClient.java:101)
>   10-26 11:58:33.404 7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter: 
>   at
>   com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.TwitterLoginButton$LoginClickListener.onClick(TwitterLoginButton.java:161)
>   10-26 11:58:33.404 7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter: 
>   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198) 10-26 11:58:33.404
>   7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter:     at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147) 10-26 11:58:33.404
>   7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 10-26 11:58:33.404
>   7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 10-26 11:58:33.404
>   7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter:     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 10-26 11:58:33.404
>   7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 10-26
>   11:58:33.404 7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter:     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 10-26 11:58:33.404
>   7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   10-26 11:58:33.404 7456-7456/com.idfcwalletapp.idfc_wallet E/Twitter: 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

and my code for fragment is:

```
public class FragmentSample extends Fragment {
    private TwitterLoginButton loginButton;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample,container,false);
        loginButton = (TwitterLoginButton)rootView. findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
        Fabric.with(getActivity(), new Twitter(authConfig));

        loginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                // The TwitterSession is also available through:
                // Twitter.getInstance().core.getSessionManager().getActiveSession()
                TwitterSession session = result.data;
                // TODO: Remove toast and use the TwitterSession's userID
                // with your app's user model
                String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
}
```

Comment: It is working now after foll changes in the container activity.    FragmentSample fragment = new FragmentSample();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
//                    transaction.add(R.id.more_activity_container, fragment).commit();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.more_activity_container,  fragment, TAG_PROFILE_FRAGMENT)
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();

Comment: where TAG_PROFILE_FRAGMENT  can be any unique flag. I had put it as private static final String TAG_SAMPLE_FRAGMENT = "sampleFragment";

Answer (score 0):

Though late here is the solution.

onActivityResult of the fragment doesnt gets called directly. It invokes the onActivityResult of your activity which calls your fragment. So override onActivityResult on your activity first as below,

```
fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(title);
if (fragment != null) {
fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Hope it works :)